# Solving recurrence relation: Product form

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

Please help in finding the solution of this recursion.

$$f(n)=\frac{f(n-1) \cdot f(n-2)}{n},$$

where $ f(1)=1$ and $f(2)=2$.

Comment: I tried that already..But it blocks the way of further thinking

Comment: I tried to visualize a tree and get the count. I also tried to find common pattern . I couldnt convert it to a solvable recursion format

Comment: With $a_n = \log f(n)$ the recursion relation becomes $a_n - a_{n-1} - a_{n-2} = -\log n$. However, finding the particular solution seems tricky though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take some large n,
$$
\begin{align}
f(n) &= \frac{f(n-1) f(n-2)}{n} \\
&= {f(n-2)^2 f(n-3) \over n (n-1)} \\
&= {f(n-3)^3 f(n-4)^2 \over n (n-1) (n-2)^2} \\
&= \frac{f(n-4)^5 f(n-5)^3}{n (n-1) (n-2)^2 (n-3)^3} \\
&= \dots \\
&=\frac{f\left(n - (n-2) \right)^{F_{n-1}} f\left(n - (n-1) \right)^{F_{n-2}}}{\prod^{n-3}_{i=0} (n-i)^{F_{i+1}}} \\
&=\frac{2^{F_{n-1}}}{\prod^{n-3}_{i=0} (n-i)^{F_{i+1}}}
\end{align}
$$
in each step until the "..." I just plugged the formula into the left factor of the numerator until I saw a pattern. The symbol $F_n$ denotes the Fibonacci sequence, which follows $F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$ and $F(0) = 0$ and $F(1) = 1$. Sorry this is not a formal proof, but you can easily prove it by induction by showing that, if it's true for some large n then it must be true for n+1, and then simply demonstrating that it's true for 3.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the formula is, for $n\geq 3$,

$$f(n) = 2^{F_{n-1}}\prod_{k=3}^{n}k^{-F_{n-k+1}}$$

where $F_1,F_2,F_3,\ldots$ is the standard Fibonacci sequence whose first two terms are $1$.

You can see this by just writing out the first several terms. For example,

$$f(9) =\dfrac{2^{21}}{3^{13}4^8 5^5 6^3 7^2 8^1 9^1}
$$

**Addendum (Inductive Proof):** The base case ($n=3$) is trivial, since
$$f(3)=\dfrac{f(2)f(1)}3=\dfrac{2\cdot 1}3 = \frac23=2^1 3^{-1}=2^{F_2}3^{-F_1}$$

For the inductive step, suppose the formula holds for $3,\ldots,n$. We show it holds for $n+1$ as follows:

$$
f(n+1)=\frac{f(n)f(n-1)}{n+1}=(n+1)^{-1}\cdot \left(2^{F_{n-1}}\prod_{k=3}^{n}k^{-F_{n-k+1}}\right) \cdot \left(2^{F_{n-2}}\prod_{k=3}^{n-1}k^{-F_{n-k}}\right)
$$

$$
= 2^{F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}}(n+1)^{-F_2}\cdot \left(n^{-F_1}\prod_{k=3}^{n-1}k^{-F_{n-k+1}}\right)\cdot \left(\prod_{k=3}^{n-1}k^{-F_{n-k}}\right)
$$

$$
= 2^{F_n}(n+1)^{-F_2}n^{-F_1}\prod_{k=3}^{n-1}k^{-F_{n-k+1}-F_{n-k}}
= 2^{F_n} \prod_{k=3}^{n+1}k^{-F_{n-k+2}}
$$

$$
=2^{F_{(n+1)-1}} \prod_{k=3}^{n+1}k^{-F_{(n+1)-k+1}}
$$

as required. $\blacksquare$

Comment: MPW, can you please also derive this formula?

Comment: I will try to formulate an inductive proof and append it to my answer. It looks like it will be easy. I just wrote out the first several terms and recognized the pattern. I suggest you do so, it's rather informative.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud: I have added the inductive proof

Answer (score 2):

As @Winther commented, letting $a_n=\log f(n)$ one has
$$a_n-a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}=-\log n.$$
We only need a particular solution. Let $F_n$ be the Fibonacci sequence $F_0=F_1=1, F_i=F_{i-1}+F_{i-2}$. And consider 
$$b_n= \sum^n_{i=0}F_i\log (n-i).$$
It is easy to show that 
$$b_n=b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}+\log n.$$

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?

Comment: MPW: It's just a different approach to your solution. Solutions to $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ is classical and gives the $2^{F_n}$ part in your answer. $b_n$ here represents the product part.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not following this from "We only need a particular solution" to the end. Is your answer intended to be some sort of hint? It surely isn't complete, and I'm not following it at all, sorry...

Comment: Yes, it was a hint. Given that $b_n=b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}+\log n$, replace $\log n$ in the relation of $a_n$'s one has $$(a_n+b_n) = (a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}) +(a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}),$$ which can be solved for any  values of $a_1$ and $a_2$.